# Embedded Python in C program seg faults when ran from script in python

Tags: python, c++, c, python-3.x, embedding

I wrote a short program trying to embed python into it
(according to the C Python Api docs : https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html):

```
#include <python3.8/Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
const char *buf1 = "def func():\n"
"    print(\"hello\")\n";

int Func(void)
{
    if (0 == Py_IsInitialized())
    {
        Py_Initialize();
    }

    printf("%s", buf1);

    PyObject* pPythonScript = Py_CompileString(buf1 , "xx" , Py_single_input);

    Py_DecRef(pPythonScript);

    Py_FinalizeEx();

    return (0);
}
}
```

I compiled it into a shared object:

```
gcc -fpic test.cpp $(python3.8-config --embed --ldflags) -c -I/usr/include/python3.8 -g
gcc -shared -o test.so test.o
```

Then I tried running this function from python:

```
from ctypes import *

path = "<abs path to shared obj>/test.so"

shared_obj = CDLL(path)

shared_obj.Func()
```

Ran the python program

```
$ python <prog name>.py
```

and it resulted with a segfault:

```
def func():
    print(hello)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Now, I've tried running the C program only (Changing the Func name into main), and all ran alright.

I ran the python program with gdb

```
gdb --args python test.py
```

and got the following:

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/python test.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
def func():
    print(hello)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000058b3b6 in PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefaultAndSize ()
```

The documentation on PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefaultAndSize yielded nothing but I know that I'm missing something, but according to the docs, it should work.

Comment: Are you trying to embed Python in a C program, and then load the resulting C program as a Python module? That sounds like a recipe for, if not disaster, then at least confusion.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to embed python in a C program.
All testing infrastructure is written in python so unfortunately my hands are tied.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue by adding a GIL lock:

```
#include <python3.8/Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
const char *buf1 = "def func():\n"
"    print(\"hello\")\n";

int Func(void)
{
    PyGILState_STATE gilstate;

    if (0 == Py_IsInitialized())
    {
        Py_Initialize();
    }

    gilstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    printf("%s", buf1);

    PyObject* pPythonScript = Py_CompileString(buf1 , "xx" , Py_single_input);

    Py_DecRef(pPythonScript);

    PyGILState_Release(gilstate);

    return (0);
}
}
```